# Jersey: adding headers to a server response

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey, I have the following method:

```
@POST
@Path("hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String hello(@FormParam("username") String username)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    CommunicationResponseM result = new CommunicationResponseM();

    String result = "hello";

    return gson.toJson(result);
}
```

So far all goes well, but now I need to add some headers. How can I do that?

Thanks!

PS:
I start the Jersey server in this way:

```
    final HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(baseUrl);
    server.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a `Response` object instead. Have a look at:
https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e5169
and
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html

These should get you on the right track...

Comment: Note: your first link has an invalid id (#d4e357)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to get the value of a header parameter from the http request, then you can use the [@HeaderParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html) annotation. It's similar to the @FormParam annotation.

If you're looking to add a header to your response, there are several ways.

- You can inject the [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) in your resource using the [@Context](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation and call the addHeader method on it.
- You can return a [Response](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) object in your method and use that to add the header. See also [ResponseBuilder](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html).

For Jersey 1, there's more info in the [Jersey 1.18 user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/index.html). See sections 2.5 and 2.13.

For the [Jersey 2 user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html), see chapter 3 and section 3.6.

Comment: This is what I'd want, but links are broken :(

Comment: I've fixed the links and added a link to the Jersey 2 user guide.